# Bad RIP value: Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!

Tags: kernel, boot, data-recovery, usb-drive, kernel-panic

Suddenly facing kernel panic, not sure what I could've done. Perhaps a forceful shutdown?

This is Tails OS booting off of a USB drive. It contains crucial data, at minimum I would like to recover it.

It says "Bad RIP Value" which makes it difficult for me to figure out what's wrong. Exitcode=0x00007f00

What are my options? Any way to fix this? Or how to recover my data?

[image]

Comment: Are there any error messages in the log before the stack trace?

Comment: There seem to be nothing before this in the boot sequence. There are some messages during boot, but they only appear momentarily and they could've been there before this error as well; nor can I seem to capture them. @dragosht

Comment: Do you have another working Linux? Have you tried mounting the partitions on the USB drive?